# Magento migration from 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2 doesn' show product in front end

Tags: magento-1.9

I have installed **Magento 1.9.1.0 with sample data**, without error. After that installed magento 2x without error. Then i migrate content from 1.9.1.0 to 2x with data migration tool, and it completed. Products and almost all informations are migrated, and i can see product in **Admin side**. But couldn't visible for other users.It showing **'We can't find products matching the selection.'**. What would be the problem???

Answer (score 0):

To show the product, check if the product following options:

```
General->Status = Enabled
general->Visibility = Catalog,Search
Inventory->Qty > 0
Inventory->Stock Availability = In Stock
Websites = checking your site
Catgories = checking your category.
```

If you want checking product to subcategory, go to Catalog->Manage Categories->Select your category, open tab Display Settings and change option "Is Anchor" to "Yes". Save category